# Project values as key and an embedded document as value in mongo

Tags: mongodb

In mongodb I have a document of structure:

```
{
    "phone":"123",
    "friends": {
                    "contacts":{
                                    "234":2,
                                    "345":5
                               }
               }
}
```

I want the output to look like :

```
{
    "123": {
                "234":2,
                "345":5
           }
}
```

I have search for multiple solution. Don't seem like getting a solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) to create custom keys (takes an array of `k-v` pairs as a parameter) and then you can use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to get custom root object, try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            phone: { $exists: true },
            "friends.contacts": { $exists: true }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            array: [{
                k: "$phone",
                v: "$friends.contacts"
            }]
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$array" }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I get this : "errmsg" : "$arrayToObject requires an object keys of 'k' and 'v'. Found incorrect number of keys:1"

Comment: @AdarshTrivedi I guess you have some objects that do not fit to the data model you provided (see here https://mongoplayground.net/p/kIFFtlRPRYL), could you filter those out ? BTW: modified my answer and added additional check for the data integrity, try now

Comment: Yes that was the  problem, missing fields in data model. Works good.